# How to fix cell size of export excel sheet because some text hide due to large text and how give color red in header of cells

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

*This is image of Export Excel file: -* [enter the image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y5t3.png)

In **index.php**, I have submit button. When I press submit button, then it redirects at **export.php** page and my excel file download, but in export excel file cell size of width and height not equal. So I want equal size of the cell for each column in export excel file.
Where I put code for **equal cell size** in this given code of export.php, *some text hides*
And I also want in the **red color** header in the export excel file

```
<?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","3-Aug-2017");
    $header = '';
    $result ='';
    $exportData = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT  * from student" ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysqli_error( ) );
    $fields = mysqli_num_fields ( $exportData );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ ){
        $header .= mysqli_fetch_field_direct($exportData,$i)->name . "\t";
    }
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $exportData ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        foreach( $row as $value ){                                            
            if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )   
     {
               $value = "\t";
            }
            else   {
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $result .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
    }
    $result = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $result );
    if ( $result == "" )
    {
        $result = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";                        
        }
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        print "$header\n$result";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't with a csv-format file (which is what you're creating at the moment). CSV is purely the data for the cells. If you want styling information as well, or to set column widths, then you need to use a native spreadsheet format file such as `BIFF` for `.xls` or `OfficeOpenXML` for `.xlsx`.... and for that your'e going to need to use a library.

PS. You really shouldn't be building your own csv-output either.... PH provides the `fputcsv()` function for precisely this purpose.